# laravel administrator - custom query on global action

Tags: php, laravel, administrator

I recently started using frozennode / Laravel-administrator.
I need to filter the results according to a field, but without using the filter option. Instead, I want to create a Global Custom Action to filter according to my criteria. Here is the code that I used on my model configuration...

```
 /**
 * This is where you can define the model's global custom actions
 */
 'global_actions' => array(
 //Filter
   'filter_approve' => array(
     'title' => 'Mostrar aspirantes sin aprobar',
     'messages' => array(
       'active' => 'Buscando...',
       'success' => 'Listo.',
       'error' => 'Ocurrió un error.',
     ),
     //the Eloquent query builder is passed to the closure
     'action' => function($query){
       //get all the rows for this query
       $query->where('name', 'John Doe');
     }
   ),
 ),
```

The application responses with an ajax call but nothing happens. So, there is something bad but I not figure what is. Any idea? Thanks in advance.